# Geom_smooth doesn't plot on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I'm trying to make a smooth curve but I don't know why is not working.
This is my dataset

```
data.fam
###specnumber_f site  position
             23   MS  on
              9   MS  on
             11   CU  on
              9   CA  on
             21   CF  on
             17   ST  on
              6   AB  on
              4   AB  on
              8   AB  on
              3   FN off
              4   FN off
             14   RO off
              6   RO off
              7 SPSP off
              4 SPSP off
              3 SPSP off
```

I need that the x-axis follow this order of sites

```
lat.order <- factor(data.fam$site, levels=c("MS", "CU", "CA", "CF", "ST", "AB", "FN",
"RO", "SPSP"))
```

Then, I tried this code but geom_smooth doesn't plot, I believe it's a simple answer by I couldn't solve it

```
ggplot(data.fam, aes(x=as.factor(lat.order), y=specnumber_f))+
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(position)), size = 2)+
  geom_smooth()
```

Comment: Probably because the x variable is discrete. Try setting the group in `geom_smooth()` to `-1` or something.

Comment: You get a "probably" answer because you did not provide a reproducible example of your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: OP, follow the suggestion of /u/teunbrand.  Change `geom_smooth()` to be `geom_smooth(aes(group=-1)` and you'll get the line.  Of course, your axis is still discrete, so it won't be a smooth line, but this way ggplot knows to connect the points.  If you want a smooth line, you will need to make a new column that is continuous, then maybe use `scale_x_continuous()` to label your breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP.  The reason your line doesn't show is due to you x axis values being discrete.  In effect, `ggplot2` does not know how to connect your data along the x axis, since with discrete data there is no obvious reason to connect along that axis.

There are two general solutions here.  One is simple and gives you a line with hard edges, whereas the other is more involved, but you will get a line that has completely smooth edges.

### Simple Solution: Not Smooth Line

To get a "not-smooth" line, all you need to do is tell `ggplot2` that the points along the x axis are all connected in that dimension and that it should use the number value of the level to assign to the x axis.  Without treating the scale numerically, there is no way to calculate a formula along that axis so this is necessary.  Since the axis is still discrete in this case, there is no point that would make sense if it were in-between any two values along x, so the line you get is going to be angular (not-smooth).  Thank @teunbrand for this solution:

```
ggplot(data.fam, aes(x=site, y=specnumber_f)) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(aes(group=-1))
```

[image]

### Getting a Smooth Line

If you are aesthetically pleased with the simple solution, then it's the easiest so go with that.  If you really wanted a smooth line, here's one way to do it.  The basic idea is that we need to change your discrete axis into a continuous one.  The problem is that `data.fam$site` is not continuous.  Therefore, we need to basically map the values of `data.fam$site` to another column that is numeric, then use `scale_x_continous()` to label our axis with the correct names from `data.fam$site`.

First, we set the order of your axis labels aside:

```
lat.order.levels <- c("MS", "CU", "CA", "CF", "ST", "AB", "FN",
                      "RO", "SPSP")
```

Then, we make another data frame that will be used to map our continuous column (herein `site_num`) onto the original data frame, `data.fam`.

```
site.data <- data.frame(
  site = lat.order.levels,
  site_num = 1:length(lat.order.levels)
)
```

Finally, we merge the two frames, keeping all the points in `data.fam`.  I create a new data.frame for this called `df`:

```
df <- dplyr::left_join(data.fam, site.data, by= "site")
```

For the plot, you assign the `x` aesthetic to `site_num`, and use `lat.order.levels` to label the axis via `scale_x_continuous()`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=site_num, y=specnumber_f)) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks=1:length(lat.order.levels),
    labels=lat.order.levels
  )
```

[image]